# Get chocolate eggs out of silicone mold

Tags: equipment, chocolate

I bought some silicone easter egg molds, and I put 2 layers of chocolate in them. After they had set I tried to turn them out of the molds and they just cracked.

Is there any trick to turning the chocolate halves out of the molds without cracking the chocolate?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "turn them out of the molds"? I have never turned a silicone mold inside out. Whatever I have made in silicone, I upend the mold and it slides out, no matter how much it would stick to other materials (muffins, cake layer, ice cubes). Rarely, some gentle tapping or shaking, or sometimes squeezing is needed. If I understood correctly, you are trying to free them of the molds like you free your foot of a sock. Won't they come out in another way?

Comment: @rumtscho : I've seen the phrase 'turn them out' used when using stiff (eg, metal) forms; I don't know the exact origins of the term, but I think if generally means turning the form over so the items fall out.

Answer (score 3):

Are you making sure that the chocolate is properly set? It's very important to ensure it's properly set or it will stick. Also, are you making the chocolate thick enough? It can be helpful to do two layers of chocolate in order that it isn't so thin it cracks easily.